# geoext popup + geoserver content.ftl

Tags: geoserver, geoext, popup

I am trying to include a jpg to a geoext popup.

There are various shapefiles, but only one needs to load pictures. With only openlayers it was easy to do, I just used the content.ftl from geoserver 2.4. However, we switched to geoext and sadly I am not able to figure out how to do it now.

Can somebody give me a hint how to force GeoExt.Popup to use the different content.ftl of geoserver - or is there another way?

Comment: By the way, my script for popup is as following:

controls.push(new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo
({
autoActivate: true,
infoFormat: "application/vnd.ogc.gml",
maxFeatures: 3,
eventListeners:
{ 
"getfeatureinfo": function(e)
{
var items = [];
Ext.each(e.features, function(feature)
{
items.push
({
xtype: "propertygrid",
title: feature.fid,
source: feature.attributes
});
});
new GeoExt.Popup
({
title: "Feature Info",
width: 200,
height: 200,
layout: "accordion",
map: app.mapPanel,
location: e.xy, 
items: items
}).show();
}
}
})
);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its working by now. Just in case someone needs the idea:
if + feature request + indexOf solved the problem ...

```
controls.push(new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
autoActivate: true,
infoFormat: "application/vnd.ogc.gml",
maxFeatures: 3,
eventListeners:{
"getfeatureinfo": function(e){
var items = [];
Ext.each(e.features, function(feature){
items.push({
xtype: "propertygrid",
title: feature.fid,
source: feature.attributes});});
var varindexof=0;
var stationidpicture="";
Ext.each(e.features, function(feature){
var s=feature.fid;
var x=String(s);
varindexof=x.indexOf("points_database");
var stationid=String(feature.attributes.stationid).toUpperCase()
stationidpicture=String('<a href="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Image/Data_Plot/'+stationid+'.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Image/Data_Plot/'+stationid+'.jpg" width="250" height="250"></a>')});
if (varindexof == -1){
new GeoExt.Popup({
title: "Feature Info",
width: 200,height: 200,
layout: "accordion",
map: app.mapPanel,
location: e.xy,
items: items}).show();}
else{
new GeoExt.Popup({
title: "Feature Info",
width: 260,height: 305,
layout: "accordion",
map: app.mapPanel,
location: e.xy,
html: "click image for bigger version" + stationidpicture }).show();}}}}));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can modify this example:

```
http://api.geoext.org/1.1/examples/popup.html
```

and add there the JPG, for example, with iFrame (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) or LightBox (http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for the idea ... however, they are just using one layer in your example - so everything is handled the same way. That is working quite well with my map too.

What I need is an way to handle different layers in different ways (meaning the getfeatureinfo - popup) or using the content.ftl of geoserver (which will differentiate the layers by itself)